# Algebra study of mathematical structure or algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Algebra can be used to study mathematical structures such as rings, fields but they are called algebraic structures.

Algebra is defined as study of structures.

Can algebra be used to study any mathematical structure or there any exceptions?

What is best way to understand and study mathematical structures if it is not in algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to give a precise answer to such a broad question, but here it is my try.

I guess it depends of what you consider to be an structure. Probably the more minimalistic to define a *structure* is a set $X$ together with some operations (as sum or multiplication, for example) or some relations (as a linear order, or the edge-relation in a graph, etc.) One example could be in this setting the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, together with sum, multiplication, and the linear order.

This object can be consider still as an algebraic object (it is an ordered field), but perhaps some people might agree that it is closer to analysis than to algebra.

Perhaps a good answer for what could be the "abstract study of structures" in the sense I described above is **model theory**, which is the study of structures from the perspective of mathematical logic.

In the more general setting, model theory looks for a classification of all possible structures given a language (which is a set of possible operations, relations, and constants) and a collection of properties. For instance, you can define a group as a structure in the language $\mathcal{L}=\{e,*\}$ (one constant, one binary operations) satisfying the following properties:

1. $\forall x\forall y\forall z (x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z)$
2. $\forall x(x*e=e*x=x)$
3. $\forall x \exists y (x*y=e)$

A set of properties is what is going to be called a *theory*.

Notice that in the example a give I am using logic symbols (such as quantifiers, equalities, etc.) as well as a direct way of quantifying. The kind of properties that you can describe will depend strongly on the kind of logic that you will use (the most studied is first-order logic, but often in analysis you find sentences such as

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N\in\mathbb{N} (n\geq N\rightarrow |x_n-a|<\epsilon)$$

which describes the idea that "the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $a$, but is not expressible in first-order logic. (at least not in an easy way)

So, to answer your question, I think that the best way to understand and study mathematical structures is through the study of model theory.

Comment: Then whether abstract algebra is sub-field of model theory?

Comment: I have the feeling that every structure in abstract algebra has the form of "a set with operations, relations and constants" (probably, even only operations and constants).